# Kendo own extension-method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How would I define my own extension-method that wraps Kendo's HtmlAttributes? I want to add bool parameter and only calls HtmlAttributes if `@item.isRequired is true`?

```
 @(Html.Kendo().RadioGroupFor(m => m.MeetingPollingQuestions)
      .Name(string.Format("PollingResponses[{0}].Value", idx))
      .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "required", data_val_required = "Question is 
      Required" })
        .Items(i=>
           {
              foreach (var option in @item.RadioButtonList)
                 i.Add().Label(option.Label).Value(option.Value);
              })
         .Value("Value")
       )
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a variable in your razor file to store the value for HtmlAttributes.

```
@{
  var htmlAttributesData = item.isRequired ? "new { required = "required", data_val_required = "Question is Required" }" : "";
}
```

Your RadioGroupFor should look like this after:

```
@(Html.Kendo().RadioGroupFor(m => m.MeetingPollingQuestions)
      .Name(string.Format("PollingResponses[{0}].Value", idx))
      .HtmlAttributes(htmlAttributesData)
        .Items(i=>
           {
              foreach (var option in @item.RadioButtonList)
                 i.Add().Label(option.Label).Value(option.Value);
              })
         .Value("Value")
       )
 }
```